# How can I embed images in an ASP.NET Generated Word File

Tags: asp.net, image, ms-word

I have a quite common problem, as I saw in the various user groups but could not find a suitable answer.

What I want to do is generate an ASP.NET page in my website which will have the option of being exported into Microsoft Word .doc format.

The method I have used is this:

```
Response.Clear();
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Test.doc");
Response.Charset = "";
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.ContentType = "application/msword";

StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
Page.RenderControl(htmlWrite);
Response.Write(sw.ToString());
Response.End();
```

However this eventhough it generates a word doc, the images are note embedded in the document, rather they are placed as links. I have looked for a way to do this, but have not found something that actually worked.

I would appreciate any help I can get, since this as "last minute" requirement
(talk about typical)

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Short Answer:** You need to provide absolute URLs for the source of the images in your page.

**Longer Answer:**

Microsoft Word will open an HTML document if you rename it with a *.doc extension.  This is what the code that you provided is doing.  In this case, the images are not embedded in the document like they would be if you created a document in actual Word format.  If your images are using relative URLs then Word will not know where to look for them, hence the need for absolute URLs.

*NOTE: This means that anyone viewing the document without an internet connection will not see the images, as they are requested from the server every time the document is opened.*

A more elegant solution would be to create the document in the real Word format.  A great library for this is [Aspose.Words](http://www.aspose.com/categories/file-format-components/aspose.words-for-.net-and-java/default.aspx).  Using this library you would be able to embed the images directly into the document so that they do not rely on the server.

Comment: Thanks AJ for your answer. The problem is that we are developing a web application that is hosted in the customers premises each time. So the approach of absolute URLs might be a little tricky. We will most probably have to try a third party library after all. Thanks anyway!

Comment: It took a while to accept the answer, but I had been working on another project so long, so I couldn't accept it without trying it out first!

Comment: Glad to hear that it was helpful...  did you end up using a third party component or going with absolute urls?  If you used a component, which one did you go with?