# expertPDF: How to match contents for converting from HTML page to PDF

Tags: css, pdf, converters

I use expertPDF to convert a HTML page to pdf format. This is a long HTML page so it's splitted in several pdf pages. I would like to adjust the size of such PDF page  to match contents

I found a topic talked about that [Export from HTML to PDF (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589852/export-from-html-to-pdf-c/1712370#1712370) and a member said that we can use Css to split the page:

ExpertPDF does a decent job of converting HTML to PDF (including images). Internally, it uses a hosted copy of IE to render the HTML before converting it, which means this component won't work with Mono on Linux, and it means IE's quirks are your PDF's quirks. That said, it does a good job of rendering moderately complex layouts, and you can control pagination with CSS page-break-before and such.

'----------------

However, I don't know how to use CSS in this situation. Anyone can explain this problem for me?

Thanks,

ThuThuy

Answer (score 1):

**ExpertPDF** breaks pages as needed. So what you need to do is mark what should *not* break. Here is a simple example of how to do this with CSS.

```
<div style="page-break-inside: avoid;">
    Content that you don't want to be broken across a page goes here.
</div>
```