# Create script that would download a webpage with image into .doc/.docx file

Tags: php

I can only see the texts in my word document while the image is just a box with X.

```
<?php
header("Content-type: application/msword");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;Filename=test.doc");
?>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <img src="http://mydomainname/Gallery/header.png" width="600px" height="110px" style="opacity:0.5;">
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: this seems to be a hard one i been googling up for days but still cant find a way and as of today no one has answer to this question yet

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display images in Word generated from HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329897/how-to-display-images-in-word-generated-from-html)

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked libraries for working with MS Word like [PHPWord](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord)?
According to its [example](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/blob/develop/samples/Sample_26_Html.php) you can save HTML as Word file.

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
   $nama_file='name_file.doc';
   header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-word");
   header("Expires: 0");
   header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
   header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=".$nama_file);
   header("Pragma: public");
```