# Display Embedded Image in Microsoft Word Document

Tags: javascript, image, ms-word

I am producing a Microsoft Word document at the client-side using JavaScript.

The Word document is essentially a file with HTML and a `.doc` extension. Word renders my text just fine but none of the "canvas" elements will show.

I've tried converting the "canvas" to "img" with "src" attribute equating to a Base64 string.

Comment: Word is no browser, I don't believe the base64 img is supported and I doubt canvas is either

Comment: Here's a similar question that may provide alternatives: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329897/how-to-display-images-in-word-generated-from-html

Comment: I had similar problem but exactly reverse. I was extracting website html and putting in word. I changed the relative URL to absolute and problem solved.